# Azure Kubernetes Nodeport service creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-nodeport

Can we add Nodeport service to aks for accessing private network in aks for the typdef service i have started implementation on Nodeport service i was facing issue with the process and which will be the best practise  for accessing in private network in aks
i have added nodeport service in deployment file and not sure it is a good practise or not

below is my pod deployment yaml file

[Pod yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of66M.png)

[pod yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V02m.png)

I have tried by using Expose command in aks but issue is not solved and typdef service should be accessed via private network how can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing AKS internal lb which will be private to your network:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb?tabs=set-service-annotations